# Workarounds for singledispatchmethod on subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.8, functools

> [The new functools.singledispatchmethod (issue32380) class interacts poorly with subclasses.
> There is no way for a sub-class to override or extend the dispatch registry.](https://bugs.python.org/issue36457)

Well that's of course `true`:

```py
# foobar.py
import functools


class FooBar:
    @functools.singledispatchmethod
    def dispatch_this(self, thing):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

```py
# foo.py 
import foobar


class FooThing:
    pass


foobar.FooBar.dispatch_this.register(FooThing, lambda x, y: f"Dispatching {y.__class__.__name__} from {x.__class__.__name__}")
```

```py
# bar.py
import foobar


class BarThing:
    pass


foobar.FooBar.dispatch_this.register(BarThing, lambda x, y: f"Dispatching {y.__class__.__name__} from {x.__class__.__name__}")
```

```py
# baz.py
import foo
import bar
import foobar


class Baz(foobar.FooBar):
    pass


print(Baz().dispatch_this(foo.FooThing()))
print(Baz().dispatch_this(bar.BarThing()))
```

If we `python baz.py` the dispatchers get registered during the imports:

```
>>> Dispatching FooThing from Baz
>>> Dispatching BarThing from Baz
```

Is there any way of working around this issue? That is "duplicating" the dispatcher method (or registry, I should say) in the *child* class?